# Database stuck in synchronized mode and another one in 'Initializing / In Recovery' mode

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

I have a database which is stuck in `Synchronized` mode and another database in `Initializing / In Recovery` mode. Both of them have been removed from their availability groups and I cannot even delete them. Both of them are in secondary server and I cant even do a failover. Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

When I try to delete the database in this state: `Initializing / In Recovery`, it says `Lock request time out period exceeded.`

When i try to delete the database in this state: `Synchronized`, it says `certain operations cannot be performed while database is in a mirroring session.`, even though I have removed it from its availability group.

Comment: Have you restarted the SQL services on that secondary node ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the query `SHUTDOWN WITH NOWAIT` on the server, then try restarting the services for the server.

Refer link for more information:
[https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/02/09/sql-server-change-pending-state-sql-server-configuration-manager/#:~:text=WORKAROUND%2FSOLUTION,and%20able%20to%20run%20queries](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/02/09/sql-server-change-pending-state-sql-server-configuration-manager/#:%7E:text=WORKAROUND%2FSOLUTION,and%20able%20to%20run%20queries).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/156181)

Comment: i have mentioned the solution found in the link here...the link contains the incident with the solution